# Simple htaccess mod rewrite with possible query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've tried and tried and tried by my htaccess knowledge isn't great, and I cannot find anything to suit my needs (but then I'm not sure what i'm searching for).

Effectively my question is twofold:

I want to convert: http://subdomain.domain.com/hello
To: http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?string=hello

But occasionally there could be a querystring as well so...
From: http://subdomain.domain.com/hello?query=true
To: http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?string=hello&query=true

So far I've managed the first:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ client.php?user=$1&$2 [L]
```

Remember, the second is a potential :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) for the last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ client.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then the original requested query will automatically appended to the new one.

Comment: Ah... it's always the simplest solution! Thank you!